# PostgreSQL xpath match with double quotes

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xpath, escaping

I'm using xpath in PostgresSQL 9.3 to search nodes with content containing double quotes.
I have tried to "\"" and "&quo t;" to replace the """, but none of them were working. "concat" seems not working either. I could not find a working method on the internet. Can anyone tell me how to escape the double quotes.

Query:

```
select
    xpath(E'//book[title = "["a book"]"]/price/text()', xmlparse(document b.content))::text[]
from
    booksite b
```

XML content like:

```
<book>
  <title>["a book"]</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath 1.0 provides no way of escaping quotes. Use single-quotes as your XPath string delimiter instead, since you can escape single quote in SQL by doubling them :

```
select
    xpath(E'//book[title = ''["a book"]'']/price/text()', xmlparse(document b.content))::text[]
from
    booksite b
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`$$` aka  Dollar-quoted String Constants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING):

```
select
    xpath( $$//book[title = '["a book"]' ]/price/text() $$ ,
           xmlparse(document b.content))::text[]
from booksite b;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5d411/21/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════╗
║ xpath ║
╠═══════╣
║ 29.99 ║
╚═══════╝
```